# How to change the icon of tab host once setup? (Android)

Tags: android-widget

I am trying to change the Icon of one of the tabs of tab host at run
time. I am not able to figure out hwo to do with the widget. could
some one let me know how its done ?

```
 spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("hello").setIndicator("hello",
       res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab1)).setContent(intent);
 tabHost.addTab(spec)
```

The xml file is as below
selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   -- When selected, use grey --
   item android:drawable="@drawable/icon1"
         android:state_selected="true" />
   -- When not selected, use white-
   item android:drawable="@drawable/icon1" 
/selector

Thanks ,
Titus

Comment: Please see my answer on this link. this will definitely help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307389/problem-running-android-hellotabwidget-example-nullpointerexception-on-addtab/7466979#7466979

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to change the icon after the TabHost (tab child) was created. This solution is not using the XML selector, this code will change the icon permanently.

```
View ic = (View) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(0).findViewById(android.R.id.icon);
ic.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_public);
```

This example will change the icon of first tab.